# java.lang.NullPointerException…crash report

Tags: java, android

I have this problem again. [In this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527219/java-lang-nullpointerexception-crash-report/16527352?noredirect=1) I had the same problem with button click sound. Nothing helped, so I disabled that sound. No other solution. And now, I have the same crash report but now in another activity with check box sound. What the hell??? I never had this crash until I disabled the other sound. So I guess if I disable this sound I will have this problem with some other sound. So that's not the solution. Here the crash report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at rs.androidaplikacije.zastaveigradovi.Izbor.onCheckedChanged(Izbor.java:126)
at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:172)
at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:52)
at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:342)
at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:127)
at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:86)
at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:72)
at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:98)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And activity code:

```
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if(music == true){
            buttonClicks.start();
            }
            }
```

Error is on this line:

```
buttonClicks.start();
```

Here's the whole class:

```
public class Izbor extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener{

    public boolean music;
    MediaPlayer buttonClicks;
    MediaPlayer buttonBack;
    RadioButton rbDesetEasy,rbDvadesetEasy,rbDesetMedium,rbDvadesetMedium,rbDesetHard, rbDvadesetHard;
    Button dNazad, dStart;
    RadioGroup rGrupa;
    TextView tv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        music = getPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox", true);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.izbor);
        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {

        Typeface dugmad = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Bebas.ttf");
        Typeface pitanjeVrh = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Lobster.ttf");


        rbDesetEasy = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rbDvadesetEasy = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        rbDesetMedium = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        rbDvadesetMedium = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio4);
        rbDesetHard = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio5);
        rbDvadesetHard = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio6);
        dNazad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNazad);
        dStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
        rGrupa = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        buttonBack = MediaPlayer.create(Izbor.this, R.raw.button31);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        buttonClicks = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);

        dNazad.setTypeface(dugmad);
        dStart.setTypeface(dugmad);
        rbDesetEasy.setTypeface(dugmad);
        rbDvadesetEasy.setTypeface(dugmad);
        rbDesetMedium.setTypeface(dugmad);
        rbDvadesetMedium.setTypeface(dugmad);
        rbDesetHard.setTypeface(dugmad);
        rbDvadesetHard.setTypeface(dugmad);
        tv1.setTypeface(pitanjeVrh);


        rGrupa.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        rbDesetEasy.setOnClickListener(this);
        rbDvadesetEasy.setOnClickListener(this);
        rbDesetMedium.setOnClickListener(this);
        rbDvadesetMedium.setOnClickListener(this);
        rbDesetHard.setOnClickListener(this);
        rbDvadesetHard.setOnClickListener(this);
        dStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(rbDesetEasy.isChecked()){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Izbor.this, Kviz.class);
                    intent.putExtra("myMethod", "nextQuestion");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else if(rbDvadesetEasy.isChecked()){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Izbor.this, Kviz20.class);
                        intent.putExtra("myMethod", "nextQuestion");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else if(rbDesetMedium.isChecked()){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Izbor.this, Kviz10Medium.class);
                        intent.putExtra("myMethod", "nextQuestion");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else if(rbDvadesetMedium.isChecked()){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Izbor.this, Kviz20Medium.class);
                        intent.putExtra("myMethod", "nextQuestion");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else if(rbDesetHard.isChecked()){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Izbor.this, Kviz10Hard.class);
                        intent.putExtra("myMethod", "nextQuestion");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else if(rbDvadesetHard.isChecked()){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Izbor.this, Kviz20Hard.class);
                        intent.putExtra("myMethod", "nextQuestion");
                        startActivity(intent);
                }   
            }
        });


        dNazad.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(music == true){
                buttonBack.start();
                }
                finish();   
            }
        });
    }

    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if(music == true){
        buttonClicks.start();
        }
        }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Probably your `buttonClicks` is `null`?

Comment: Are you sure `R.raw.click` exists and is spelled correctly?

Comment: `if(music == true){` is not good style, `if(music){` is much better...

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882851/mediaplayer-create-always-returns-null)

Comment: @codeMagic Yes I am sure, it works fine on my phone.

Comment: @jlordo is that important or just for style sake?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Why do you think it's null? And how could it be null when it's working fine in most cases? I only have a few of those crash reports.

Comment: Try using a `null` check and adding a log message and then let it just crash in order to see if this is what happens: `if (buttonClicks == null) { logger.log("buttonClicks is null and app will crash"); } buttonClicks.start();`

Comment: Can it be possible that some devices don't support the sound file format?

Comment: Well, I don't know. It's mp3. My toster support mp3.

Comment: @marjanbaz: There is no different in the logic. But this `if(music){` will enter the block if `music` is `true`, whereas this `if(music == true){` will enter the block if `music` compared to `true` is equal. Your version is something typically written by beginners (I probably wrote it too, when starting to program) ;)

Comment: OK, I will change it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `MediaPlayer` appears to be `null` even though you try to instantiate it here

```
R.raw.click
```

According to the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29)

> Returns
>   a MediaPlayer object, or null if creation failed

so this tells us that your `R.raw.clicks` is probably missing, spelled incorrectly, or otherwise unavailable. This is causing the `MediaPlayer` creation to fail, hence leaving your `buttonClicks` as `null`

Comment: It's not missing, it's spelled correctly. It works on my phone, and on my girlfriend's phone. I can hear it. And I have around 10 000 downloads for this app, and only few of these crash reports, so it works fine in the rest of the cases.

Comment: @marjanbaz Are you sure it's not related to the specific phone's model?

Comment: Well, I don't know that. Google does not share that info with crash report. Maybe.

Comment: It must have something to do with accessing the `MediaPlayer` object itself the `raw resources` file on specific devices. Either way, it appears to be due to the `MediaPlayer` object not getting created. I would put a check in there before you call any method on it and if its `null` then tell the user their media player isn't compatible or something